# Binaries (bin) not updating on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I am working on a project in Visual Studio that is under source control. I changed the Assembly Name and therefore the name of the assembly dll was changed. If I clean the solution and then build it then the DLLs are updated in the bin held locally. I do not have the bin in source control. I am then deploying to a server for testing using MSBuild. Now I am getting an error when I go to the website on the server because it appears that the DLLs on the server are not being updated. When I use MSBuild, I have 'Clean Workspace' set to 'All', which should clean the solution and then build again  on the server. But that doesn't appear to be happening. I cannot find where the Bin directory is on the server to check either.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when MSBuild or WebDeploy needs to overwrite the old executable/library but fails to because some process is still accessing it, MSBuild doesn't do a lot to let you know.

If you have access to the server go to the directory (usually C:\inetpub\wwwroot\\bin) and try to remove the old files yourself (may require killing a w3m process) and then redeploy.